# Function to parse a Javascript object and return a CSV

Tags: javascript, json, csv

This function converts a Javascript Object into a CSV.

```js
var dataFromAPI = [{"name":"first"},{"name":"sec,ond"},{"name":"third 'jibberish"},{"name":"fourth, jibberish"}]

function convertToCSVandDownload(objArray) {
    var csvOutput = "";
    Object.keys(objArray).forEach(function(key) {
      if (csvOutput.length == 0) {
        csvOutput = "Index,Field Value\n";
        csvOutput = csvOutput + JSON.stringify(key) + "," + JSON.stringify(objArray[key]["name"]) + "\n";         
      } else {
        csvOutput = csvOutput + JSON.stringify(key) + "," + JSON.stringify(objArray[key]["name"]) + "\n";                 
      }
    })
    return csvOutput;
}

console.log(convertToCSVandDownload(dataFromAPI));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

It would appear that your current solution is a bit complicated. Using `JSON.parse` just to ensure that you escape `,` is overkill.

The overall solution can be drastically simplified as you will see in this post.

#### `const` before `let` and `let` before `var`

All variables should be declared by default with `const`. If a variable is going to be mutated then use `let`. Don't use `var` unless that is what you intended.

```
/// bad
var dataFromAPI = ...
```

```
/// good
const dataFromAPI = ...
```

*note: pushing an element to a list will only mutate the array and not the variable, thus no error*

---

Work with arrays and not with strings.

```
/// bad
csvOutput = "Index,Field Value\n";
```

```
/// good
const csvOutput = [
  ["Index", "Field", "Value"]
];
```

---

Function names should describe what they do.

The `convertToCSVandDownload` method only converts to CSV but doesn't download. Change the name to `convertToCSV`

---

## Working Solution

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const dataFromAPI = [{"name":"first"},{"name":"sec,ond"},{"name":"third 'jibberish"},{"name":"fourth, jibberish"}]

function convertToCSV(data, headers) {
  return data
  .reduce((a,{name},i)=>[...a, [i, `"${name}"`]], [headers])
  .map(row=>row.join(","))
  .join("\n");
}

const res = convertToCSV(dataFromAPI, ["Index", "Field Value"]);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

*I'd like to propose a solution using `flatMap`. Be aware that this is definitely not a cross-browser solution.*

---

Let's create a function that given *n* arguments returns a CSV line:

```js
const row = (...args) => args.map(JSON.stringify).join(',');

console.log(row('foo'));
console.log(row('foo', 'bar'));
console.log(row('foo', 'bar', 'baz'));
```

Then let's use `flatMap` to append (or prepend) stuff while we map over an array. e.g.:

```js
const pair = arr => arr.flatMap(n => [n, n]);

console.log(pair([1]));
console.log(pair([1, 2]));
console.log(pair([1, 2, 3]));
```

As you can see we can use `flatMap` to "add" more items as we iterate. Let's use this to add the headers during the first iteration.

**Complete solution**

```js
const dataFromAPI = [
  {"name": "first"},
  {"name": "sec,ond"},
  {"name": "third 'jibberish"},
  {"name": "fourth, jibberish"}];
  

const row = (...args) => args.map(JSON.stringify).join(',');

const csv =
  dataFromAPI
    .flatMap((obj, idx) =>
      idx === 0 ?
        [row('Index', 'Field Value'), row(idx, obj.name)] :
        [row(idx, obj.name)])
    .join('\n');
    
console.log(csv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Skimming through your code I believe ya may not need that `if`/`else` check within the `.forEach` loop...

```js
var dataFromAPI = [{"name":"first"},{"name":"sec,ond"},{"name":"third 'jibberish"},{"name":"fourth, jibberish"}]

function convertToCSVandDownload(objArray) {
    var csvOutput = "Index,Field Value\n";
    Object.keys(objArray).forEach(function(key) {
        csvOutput = csvOutput + JSON.stringify(key) + "," + JSON.stringify(objArray[key]["name"]) + "\n";
    })
    return csvOutput;
}

console.log(convertToCSVandDownload(dataFromAPI));
```

... and one thing that might be an improvement may be allowing for converting other *`target_key`s*...

```js
var dataFromAPI = [{"name":"first"},{"name":"sec,ond"},{"name":"third 'jibberish"},{"name":"fourth, jibberish"}]

function convertToCSVandDownload(objArray, target_key) {
    var csvOutput = "Index,Field Value\n";
    Object.keys(objArray).forEach(function(i) {
        csvOutput += JSON.stringify(i) + "," + JSON.stringify(objArray[i][target_key]) + "\n";
    })
    return csvOutput;
}

console.log(convertToCSVandDownload(dataFromAPI, 'name'));
```

... other than those two things I think you code is good, and the only other thing ya might want to consider is what ya want to do with data structures that have more *layers* than `dataFromAPI`

Comment: Is 'ya' Jamaican?

Comment: The [urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ya%20man) says something like _"Term for "yes" used in Jamaica"_, but that is just something that I read online somewhere. Personally I use it for that as well as a less direct form of _`you`_, eg. _"ya ya could do that'_, which when spoken would have a more `uh` like sound on the second `ya`.